# Troubles sending textarea data to a database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, forms

I'm trying to create a php form that sends textarea data to database. The database table **uploads** has 3 data items that are needed:

- **user_id**
- **category**
- **content**

---

HTML:

```
<form id="myform" action="php/savetext.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <p><strong>Add your story here.</strong></p>

        <input type="hidden" name="fbid" id="fbid">
        <input type="hidden" name="category" id="category">

        <textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="usertext" id="storyArea"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Saada" />

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $( "#fbid" ).val( "sdf88d99sd" );
            $( "#category" ).val( "texts" );    

        </script>                       
</form>
```

**savetext.php:**

```
include_once('config.php');

if (isset($_POST['user_id']) && isset($_POST['category']) && isset($_POST['usertext'])) {

    $user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fbid']);
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
    $content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usertext']);
    addUser($user_id, $category, $content);
}

else {
    echo 'Upload failed! Try again.';
}

function addUser($user_id, $category, $content) {
    $query = "SELECT id FROM uploads WHERE user_id = '$fbid' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($rows > 0) {
        $query = "UPDATE uploads SET user_id = '$user_id', category = '$category' WHERE content = '$content'";
    }
    else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO uploads (user_id, category, content) VALUES ('$user_id', '$category', '$content')";
    }
    mysql_query($query);
    echo 'Upload was succesful. Thank you!';

}
```

But this doesn't work. Any ideas on how to correct this?

Comment: the update should use primary key in where condition not the long text.

Comment: 2nd thing the function must have access to the connection string !!

Comment: are you using any editor for textarea

Comment: A word of advice... don't use the PHP mysql_* functions they are deprecated, you should use PDO or mysqli in their place.

Comment: @Karthick Kumar Ganesh - Not using any editor for the textarea.

Comment: @MartinMetsalu you need to load some data in textarea using jquery am i right

Comment: @micb Can I simply change mysql_ to mysqli_?

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh - Upon user submit I need to get the inserted data to a database. Later on I will be showing the data in a results area, but first I need to get the data and store it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please review this code ,there is no field with name user_in in `<form></form>`

```
if (isset($_POST['fbid']) && isset($_POST['category']) && isset($_POST['usertext'])) {

    $user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fbid']);
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
    $content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usertext']);
    addUser($user_id, $category, $content);
}
```

Comment: I completely missed that. Now the inserted data gets saved to a database. Also got this error: `Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given on line 20`. Do you know what is causing it?

Comment: this is because your $result may be null or empty